# save a result obtained and transcribe it on another page

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know how to save the result obtained on one page and transcribe it on another page in html page thks

on the first page ;

```
 <script>
        const totalPrice = document.getElementById("total-price");
        
        
        localStorage.setItem("totalPrice", totalPrice.innerText);
        </script>
```

and on the second page;

```
 <script>
            const totalPrice = localStorage.getItem("totalPrice");
        </script>
```

Comment: You can using localStorage

Comment: you already have a sort of solution. what doesn't work?

Comment: thks to all , I put this on the first pagescript>
        const totalPriceElement = document.getElementById("total-price");
        const totalPrice = totalPriceElement.innerHTML; // Récupérer la chaîne de caractères entière du prix total
        localStorage.setItem("total-Price", totalPrice); // Stocker la chaîne de caractères entière dans le stockage local
      </script>

Comment: and on the second page I put this<script>
        const totalPrice = localStorage.getItem("total-Price");
        const totalCommandeElement = document.getElementById("total-commande");
        totalCommandeElement.innerHTML += `<p>${totalPrice}</p>`;
     </script> and it's good